# error launching simple web app in docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image: screenshot]

That is what I get when I follow the instructions at the official Docker tutorial here:  [tutorial link](https://docker-curriculum.com/)

I uploaded my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file and followed all other instructions.

The logs show nothing even when I click Request:

[image: error screen2]

If anyone has a clue as to what I need to do, ie. why would not having a default VPC even matter here?  I have only used my AWS account to set up Linux Machine EC2 instances for a Deep Learning nanodegree at Udacity in the past (briefly tried to set up a VPC just for practice but am sure I deleted/terminated everything when I found out that is not included in the free tier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the official tutorial forgot to add that you have to add the tag to the image name in the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file per below in gedit or other editor where `:firsttry` is the tag:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "hockeymonkey96/catnip:firsttry",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "5000"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

It works:

[image]